# Which download is correct for Oracle Java EE SDK 6 on linux?

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, java-6

I need to install the EE SDK 6 (not 7 or 8) on my linux computer and every search seems to turn up a different download. I also notice there are no RPMs anymore, but instead it's a ".sh" file. Is that correct?

Here's what I've found:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-6u29-downloads-523388.html

And this page doesn't show update 4 for EE 6, only update 3:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eesdk-419427.html

Which is the correct one?

Comment: I want to make sure you're getting what you want.  You mention EE SDK 6 but then reference 8.  There isn't a version 8 of *EE* (yet) but there is of the JDK.  Do you mean the EE developer libraries or the JDK?  An EE 6 *server* would be GlassFish 3.x (https://glassfish.java.net/download-archive.html).

Comment: @stdunbar Did not know there wasn't an 8 of EE yet, I assumed there was since JDK has an 8. I mean EE.

Comment: Ok, then you need either of those two - they are both EE 6.  I updated my first comment to point you to one possibility.  Another one is JBoss7 - http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads